# What kind of files, graphics, and information would be in an "identity starter kit?"

Tags: branding, identity

I am a first year design student, and my uncle informally asked me to create a logo for him. He is working with a woman who helps people grow their business by getting them on social media and building them websites.

So I sent her the logo, but it turns out that she was really looking for me to create an identity for him. She says that she isn't a graphic designer, and asked "What do you suggest as a basic starter kit for him?"

Since I have no experience with this, I have no idea what should be included in an "identity folder," as she called it. Could anyone help me out? What kind of graphics, information, etc. should I be sending her, and what kinds of files? A very detailed answer would be highly appreciated... I don't know what I'm doing!

Comment: Might be useful (even though it's on Writers): "What needs to be included in a corporate style guide?"  http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/what-needs-to-be-included-in-a-corporate-style-guide/2592#2592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, an **Identity kit** (or **Brand Guidelines**) isn't so much about including *specific* images.

There will be *some* imagery but it's more about usage. You detail items such as:

- **Logo versions:** All variations of *approved* usage from 1 color to full color and reversed including required space around the logo, what *not* to do with the logo, etc.
- **Approved symbolism:** If there are symbols, icons, etc which the brand uses this would entail usage requirements for *each* of those. Similar to the logo requirements - colors, variations, etc.
- **Brand color guide:** What colors to use in RGB, HEX, CMYK, and Spot (Pantone)
- **Typefaces:** What typefaces to be used and where.
- If applicable **product imagery** to be used: What images can be used and in what situations they are approbate.
- In some cases **approved copy** (text) may be included. Such as approved tag lines to use. Approved "benefit" copy to be used, etc.

As a whole, an identity kit is a basic **"this is what we look like overall"** document. It's *not* a here's an ad to use, here's a brochure to use, here's a poster to use, document. You are free to include templates for things like posters, brochures, etc. but they aren't generally a staple of the "kit".

As a starting point, *[take a look at a few brand guideline documents](https://www.google.com/search?q=brand+guidelines+pdf&safe=off&hl=en&biw=1087&bih=1389&site=imghp&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=CLfCVO6bMavbsATbzYEI&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAA&dpr=1)* and get a general idea.

Comment: Great advice. Just wanted to chime in and add a couple of resources for the budding identity designer that I'm finding helpful. [Graham Smith's site](http://imjustcreative.com/?s=templates) is great. Not only does he do great logo/identity design work but he blogs, inspires and otherwise helps out the design community as well. [Brand New](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/) is another fantastic website for identity inspiration. You should be able to pick up you some ideas about what a great identity does and does not usually entail from there.

Answer (score 0):

In the best possible suggestion I can give, I'd supply a 'Branding Guidelines', the different versions of the logo, materials for the business, and mock ups to illustrate what everything would look like.